# Use of exit() in C

Tags: c, linux

If my main function calls foo(), which calls foo2(), which has only one statement:

> `exit(1);`

Would my main function exit with 1 too?

edit: what if I have a fork in main(), and call foo in my child, then

```
wait(&status);
```

What would the WEXITSTATUS be?

Comment: No, exit terminates the *process* that the program is running in, setting the exit status to `1`. Your main function will technically never return. [`man exit(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, no. The program terminates at the point exit() is called. Functionally there'd be no external difference between

```
int main() {
   return 1;
}
```

and

```
int foo(2) {
   exit 1;
}
```

The external calling app will simply get an exit status of 1, and has no way of telling if it was from a return in main, or an exit in foo.

Comment: It's `exit(1)`and not `exit 1`.

Comment: And paramter name is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`exit` itself doesn't return, but your program will have an exit status of `1`, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively yes. `exit` exits the *entire program* with the given status code. If you return a value from `main`, the C standard says that the result is as though you had called `exit` with the same value. So if you call `exit` yourself, `main` never truly returns, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you `fork()`, then the child process will terminate with status 1, which will be assigned to variable `status` of the parent process (the one that started main()).

Be careful, however, on how `fork()` works, as the foo() function might be called in both processes, in which case your main process would be terminated with exit status 1 as well. If you have to check if the value returned by fork() (the process id / pid). PID = -1 there was an error, PID = 0, you are in the child process; otherwise, you are in the parent process.

References: http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait
http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit